# Pessoa X pessoal

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu sempre usava **oi pessoa** mas recentimente vi **oi pessoal**!

Há diferença entre essas duas frases? Ainda uma vez vi: **Oi Ana, pessoal**!! O que é esse "pessoal" depois de um nome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Brasil, usamos a palavra *pessoal* quase invariavelmente com o [sentido](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=pessoal) de *reunião de indivíduos por qualquer motivo* – ora como vocativo, ora ao designar a natureza de tal reunião, como em `O pessoal do basquete`. Assim, a expressão `Oi, pessoal` é uma maneira comum de cumprimentar todos presentes.

A expressão `Oi, pessoa`, apesar de compreensível, não é idiomática e, por dar a entender que existe a possibilidade de o nome do interlocutor não ter sido lembrado, pode ser considerada levemente insultante por alguns.

Construções do tipo `Oi, Ana, pessoal!` não são comuns. A única situação que consigo conceber em que tal expressão seria idiomática é quando se cumprimenta Ana primeiro – seja por motivos de deferência, seja apenas por tê-la visto antes dos outros – e imediatamente depois se cumprimenta o resto do grupo.

Comment: “Oi, pessoa” parece que se está falando com apenas uma pessoa, porém “oi, pessoas” me tem duas impressões: uma parecida de a de com “oi, humanos” e a outra é de menos familiaridade com quem se fala.

Comment: Nenhuma das três expressões me parece gramaticalmente errada em si, mas, enquanto ”Oi, pessoas“ eu até consigo imaginar sendo usada em algum fórum online onde não se conhece com quem se está falando, ’Oi, pessoa” soa-me muito estranha. Àqueles que não conheço, diria apenas “Oi”; àqueles que conheço, dizer tal expressão soa-me similar a dizer “Oi, mulher” ao me dirigir a minha própria mãe.

Answer (score 1):

Já ouvi usarem "oi, pessoa", e também "oi, pessoinha" em tom carinhoso ao se dirigir a uma criança, mas nada disso é idiomático. Geralmente é dito em tom jocoso e implica uma certa intimidade. Por isso não recomendo o seu uso ao dirigir-se a estranhos. Poderia soar ofensivo.

Já a palavra "pessoal" é bem comum, seja como um vocativo ou como substantivo/adjetivo.

- "**Pessoal**, chegou a hora de cantarmos o parabéns."
- "Ei, **pessoal**, peço que vocês se aproximem do palco."
- "O **pessoal** queria entrar no estádio de qualquer maneira."
- "Isso é algo muito **pessoal**. Nada posso falar a respeito."

Quanto ao "Oi Ana, pessoal!!" o único contexto que me ocorre já está bem descrito na resposta de Bourbaki Wannabe.